# How to install JSPRINT SETUP extension from file to Firefox

Tags: firefox

I was using JsPrint Setup extension with Firefox 56 for directly print barcodes from barcode printer (Pc has 2 printers). I had to reinstall windows to pc. Now I cant download JsPrint Setup extension from Addons firefox. I think they removed it. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/

I found zip file on github but firefox doesnot accept the zip file I downloaded from https://github.com/edabg/jsprintsetup.

How can I install this extension or is there any other extension or way for silent print from a specific printer?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1: type about:addons on the addressbar of old firefox
2: click the gear on the upper right
3: click install add-on from file

old firefox only..., not supported on later versions